# How to fix a stripped hole?

Tags: repair, hole

I have a hole that a head of as bolt goes into, but the hole is stripped and cannot get a good grip on the bolt head. The hole is attached to an agitator which spins. Any help? Remember, only the head of the bolt goes inside the hole, nothing else.

Comment: If the hole is metal and you don't want to go to the next size bolt, the only thing I can think of is to braze or solder a bit of metal to the hole. That, or bolt a plate to the metal in question and drill an appropriately sized hole, assuming you have enough space to play with to attach such a plate.

Comment: What if you did something like cement a nut of the appropriate size into the stripped-out hold with a material like JB Weld, then you might be able to cut the head off the bolt and thread it into the cemented nut. That's presuming you still need to be able to separate whatever two parts are mating together at some point in the future. Otherwise, I suppose you might be able to cement the bolt head itself in there.

Comment: What kind of bolt head is it? There are many kinds. One kind that is designed to engage a hole is a [carriage bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_bolt). Is that what you have?